# Ruby doesn't generate an exception when a stored procedure doesn't exist in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ruby, stored-procedures, message, aptana3

I have this simple fairly code under the following

```
$: << File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config")
$: << File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../lib")

require 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
require 'sa.gw.library'
require 'sa.gw.lib.connection_manager'

#connecting to sqlserver test
@app_config = YAML.load_file("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../config/sa.gw.c.victim.yml")
connection_manager = ConnectionManager.new(@app_config["tpaldb"]) #H

begin  
    sql = "exec spTPal_Vic_GetDeviceStateByIMEI '000000000000000'"
    result = connection_manager.execute_sproc(sql)
          result.each {|r|

          puts 'hello'           
          }             
    connection_manager.connection.close()
    rescue => e
      puts "An error occurred  detail: #{e.message}"  

    end
```

I am executing this routine using Aptana Studio 3. What I've experienced is this that the function terminates silently if Stored Procedure doesn't exists without letting user know.
what I want to have a mechanism is to know the procedure doesn't exist in the form message or exception.

stack trace is under the following

```
["c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:416:in `each'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:416:in `handle_to_names_and_values_dblib'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:405:in `handle_to_names_and_values'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:377:in `_raw_select'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:371:in `block in raw_select'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:371:in `raw_select'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:354:in `do_exec_query'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:24:in `exec_query'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:297:in `select'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'", "c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'", "J:/SecureAlert_SVN/2.0.5 (Chilli)/lib/sa.gw.lib.connection_manager.rb:27:in `execute_sproc'", "J:/SecureAlert_SVN/2.0.5 (Chilli)/app/controllers/publisher_test.rb:16:in `<main>'"]
```

Comment: What kind of error should be raised if that procedure doesn't exist?  You aren't rescuing anything, so it doesn't know what you want to rescue.  `rescue Exception => e` should get you started.  But you probably don't want to rescue that specific (parent of all) exception.  Find one that is closest to exactly what should be rescued.

Comment: Strange! when I debugged the code that went inside Sql Server classes then it showed me that error. When I debugged it and step through the code then it terminates silently and when I ran the application then again it showed me the error.

Comment: You should show the stacktrace and explain that in your question then.

Comment: Please review the stack trace in the question

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, the default rescued exception is going to be `StandardError`.  What you have shown here doesn't show what error was raised, or perhaps it was raised from SQL rather than from Ruby.

You are rescuing StandardError then, as you don't specify the exception you are trying to rescue, and it may indeed be the wrong one.